# kernel panic - not syncing. No ini found. Ubuntu 12.04 along side Windows 7 dual boot

Tags: installation, dual-boot, kernel, boot-repair

I was able to boot into Ubuntu 13.04 from a live usb and do an installation on my HP NE56R31u which came with Windows 8 pre-installed, but which I since got a tech to change to Windows 7 instead.

However, after a successful installation along side Windows, upon reboot, I would get a black screen with a blinking cursor. Tried several of the fixes recommended here but none of them worked, and one of them made me unable to get to Grub, which made me unable to boot into even Windows and I became afraid. I at least want to have one os working on my machine.

Since it's been a few days and I am still unable to get Ubuntu to work despite begging for answers, I did a re-install, but this time with 12.04 LTS.

Once again the installation completed fine, but upon reboot, nothing. The error message this time is `Kernel panic - not syncing. No init found. Try passing init=option to kernel.`

I booted in again using the live usb and ran a `boot repair`. You can find the results here.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6131996/

There are two things that stood out for me during the boot repair:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of overlayfs cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
```

and

```
(glade2script:16608): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.MTNG3W': No such file or directory

(glade2script:16608): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab overlayfs / overlayfs rw 0 0 tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0 /dev/sda5 swap swap defaults 0 0 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Can someone please help me? It's been WEEKS!

Comment: why not just reinstall with 13.04? if that worked before...

Comment: boot-repair messed your "home encryption", that's about the first warning. The second can be ignored, but I see a `cat` command mixed there, apparently your call. About the kernel panic seems that using 64-bits have problems, try using 32-bits with UEFI shutdown.

Comment: 13.04 did not "work before".  None of the installations have worked, just the live usb boots.

Answer (score -1):

I'm probably barking up the wrong tree here, but have you tried turning off Secure Boot and/or using BIOS compatibility mode?  Assuming that those options are available in your BIOS... er.. UEFI.

This might have useful information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Did you install the 64bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: This is not the issue.

Comment: 13.04, just like 12.04 worked only using the live usb, not from the installation.  I am using Legacy Bios and Secure Boot is disabled.  And yes, I've been installing the 64 bit version of Ubuntu in both cases.